# Python Tkinter Цветной текст

Tags: python, tkinter

Хочу реализовать цветной вывод как на картинке, только не в консоли, а в tkiter'овский label.
Есть ли такая возможность? Если да, то как?

```py
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
lbl = Label(window, text='normal text\nred text')
lbl.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

На картинке пример из модуля colorama[image: Картика из модуля colorama]

Comment: опубликуйте пожалуйста пример, который у вас есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Виджет `Text` позволяет выводить текст разным цветом:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

text = tk.Text()
text.pack()

# Для тега 'tag_red_text' задаем красный цвет текста
text.tag_config('tag_red_text', foreground='red')

text.insert(tk.END, 'normal text\n')  # Добавляем обычный текст
text.insert(tk.END, 'red text', 'tag_red_text')  # Добавляем текст с тегом tag_red_text (таким образом, делаем текст красным)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: Скриншот]

Answer (score 1):

Просто добавте в Label - fg

```
root = Label(text='test', fg="green")
```

если надо задний фон, то просто используйте вместо fg  - bg

Полный пример:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
lbl = Label(window, text='normal text')
lbl.pack()

lb = Label(window, text='red text', fg='red')
lb.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что текст требуется сделать выборочно цветным

Comment: @user393203, сделайте 2 label с текстом разного цвета, расположите их рядом - вот вам и выборочно цветной текст.